# Ssh in redhat to access webcam of remotehost

Tags: linux, rhel

Ssh -X  cheese 
This command used in redhat 7.5 to access webcam of remotehost ,I want to know '-X' argument from where it's come?

Comment: This question needs clarification.  Are you asking what the purpose is of the `-X` option?

Answer (score 1):

man ssh:
-X      Enables X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this page: https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1

[image: OpenBSD Manual]

`-X` enables X11 forwarding and
`-x` disables X11 forwarding.